# Unable to log in after update Elementary OS

Tags: release-hera, greeter

This morning I update My Elementary OS, but after update has finished, I can not log in to my Elementary OS, it says, "session returned error code 1"
I've try to install the newest graphic driver but the problem is still unsolved. Please help me, I'm so noob in linux. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and try to log in. and please provide screenshots as i think your update was related to a nvidia driver update.